# How to open a popup shell without closing the previous one

Tags: java, shell, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am using this [PopupComposite](http://palea.cgrb.oregonstate.edu/svn/jaiswallab/Annotation/src/ie/dcu/swt/PopupComposite.java) and i would like to know how to open a popup shell(pc1) containing a button, which opens another popup shell(pc2), without closing the first popup shell. I tried modifying the PopupComposite's activation listener, but all i got was a solution that flickers pc1 everytime i open pc2. I added the following code in shellActivated:

```
if(shell.getParent() != null)
            shell.getParent().setVisible(true);
```

Whenever the popups lose focus they have to hide(i can't use FocusListener for shells, since it doesn't work on mac).

Here's my tester:

```
public class TestShells
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));



        final Composite container = new Composite(shell, SWT.NULL);
        container.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        final Button btn = new Button(container, SWT.PUSH);
        btn.setText("Button 1");

        final PopupComposite pc1 = new PopupComposite(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), SWT.NULL);
        final Button btn2 = new Button(pc1, SWT.PUSH);
        btn2.setText("Button 2");

        final PopupComposite pc2 = new PopupComposite(pc1.getShell(),SWT.NULL);
        final Text text = new Text(pc2, SWT.BORDER);

        btn.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener()
        {

            public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e)
            {
                pc1.show(btn.getLocation());
            }

            public void widgetDefaultSelected(final SelectionEvent e)
            {
            }
        });

        btn2.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener()
        {

            public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e)
            {
                pc2.show(btn2.getLocation());

            }

            public void widgetDefaultSelected(final SelectionEvent e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to hide the previous window, but I as a Windows user can also tell you that it's often found frustrating to have a pop-up dissapear beneath a pile of programs, so would advise against that.

As to the actual question: have you tried `JDialog`? Just stack a `JOptionPane` in the dialog window that'll be displayed upon a button being pressed.

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

EDIT: here's the code snippet that should work, I haven't tested it.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MessageBox;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class Snippet99 {

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    final private Display display = new Display();
    final private Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    final Composite container = new Composite(shell, SWT.NULL);
        container.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final private Button btn = 
new Button(container, SWT.PUSH).setText("Button 1");
    final private PopupComposite pc1 = 
new  PopupComposite(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), SWT.NULL);
    final private Button btn2 = 
new Button(pc1, SWT.PUSH).setText("Button 2");
    final private PopupComposite pc2 = 

new PopupComposite(pc1.getShell(),SWT.NULL);

    private Text text = new Text(pc2, SWT.BORDER);
    /*
    only use final if you're setting the value immediately and will never change it again,
    make sure you set the accessibility of your items (protected/private/public)
    */

    Listener listener = new Listener() {
      public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        pc1.show(btn.getLocation());
      }
    };

    btn.addListener(SWT.Selection, listener);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but i am only allowed to use SWT.

Comment: @JNewbie That changes matters. In that case, look at this example that modifies closing behavior: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/Preventashellfromclosingprompttheuser.htm

Comment: already tried that, but my condition cannot be verified at that point since the shell that i am going to open next, opens only after this one closes

Comment: Then why do you state in your first post that you want to keep them both open?

Comment: I want to keep them open. But the first one always closes when i open the second one.

Comment: Then my comment stands, you should look at his example and add the logic for your second screen into the place where he gives the confirmation dialog and modify the actionlistener to show this new pop-up when you press a button, instead of closing screen 1.

Comment: If you have not yet figured this out tonight I'll probably have time to give some demo code, so please let me know if it's needed or not.

Comment: I'll try to do it myself right now, but if you have time, i could use an example, sure. Thank you very much